# Resource limit on SQL Server Linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I'm frequently receiving the error on a stored procedure that uses openquery to read via a linked server.

> The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "BrackleyICS"
>   reported an error. Execution terminated by the provider because a
>   resource limit was reached.

This will usually happen at 10.01 minutes.  This would imply a timeout setting, however on other occasions it will run fine taking 35 minutes to complete.

Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: Maybe login timeouts one time and do not other time, this may help: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/314530/error-message-when-you-execute-a-linked-server-query-in-sql-server-timeout-expired

Comment: Taken from above link,  By default, in Microsoft SQL Server 7.0, the timeout setting is zero (0 - infinite wait). By default, in SQL Server 2000 and in SQL Server 2005, the timeout setting is 600 (10 minutes).

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I've been experiencing this on and off for about 2 years, and I have never identified the cause.

Answer (score 4):

You can check you current timeout settings by:

> query timeout

right click server > Properties > Connections > Remote Query Timeout

> login timeout

right click server > Properties > Advanced > Remote Login Timeout

I think your login timeout is set to 10 mins, you need to increase this by running below script, change value from 30 seconds to required one

```
sp_configure 'remote login timeout', 30
go 
reconfigure with override 
go
```

Reason why it is not timeouts every time:
Not sure but if user ids logged on to server then timeout doesn't happen.

Comment: I did think it had something to do with this, I'm just confused about why it sometimes times out and other times it doesn't.

So Server A connects to Server B with OpenQuery, sometimes it times out and other times it doesn't.  Server A also connects to Server C also using OpenQuery and this never times out, but takes longer.

Comment: @Jay1b, compare Server B and Server C settings, maybe there you spot some diffrence

Comment: There are no obvious settings difference that could affect this.  Needless to say SQL Server is so vast I can't say that all settings are the same.  Changing this timeout to 300 from 600 does mean it times out at 5 minutes instead as expected.  I'm trying a few runs with this set to an hour (3600), just harder to confirm success when it was occasionally working anyway.

Comment: @PawelCzapski I have server A query data from server B by OpenQuery, which server should I update above setting?

Answer (score 0):

Linked server has also its own Query Timeout setting in Linked Server->Properties->Server Options. It is likely it is set to 0 - which is default value.

In this case it is using Query Wait advanced server setting - which again - most likely is set to -1 (default).

In this case timeout is decided per query and it is calculated as 25 times of estimated query cost.

More info in [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186839(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`EXEC sys.sp_configure N'remote query timeout (s)', N'1800'
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO`

The default value is 600 s which is equal to 10 min

Comment: Please provide more detail on the answer, don't just paste a block of code.